# Can I emulate the fast type of array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

***JavaScript: The Good Parts*** by Douglas Crockford, **Chapters 6**, ***Arrays***, paragraph 1:

> "An *array* is a linear allocation of memory in which elements are
>   accessed by integers that are used to compute offsets. Arrays can be
>   very fast data structures. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have
>   anything like this kind of array."

I keep finding examples of people doing incredible things with JavaScript, so I'm curious to know whether we can (or can't) emulate this true array data structure in JavaScript. **How can it be done, or why can't it?**

For example, I thought of using a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) for building and working on this data structure, since any object-based structure will just be bound by the usual core Object speed/performance constraints.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi well then! It would seem the work is done for me. I always find myself so lucky - If I'd been born 10 years earlier, I'd have been constrained by having to do so many things from scratch which have been added to JavaScript and Web Specifications to allow us Web developers to *work* less and *do* more. Still progress to be made in terms of performance of CSS and the DOM, but even in those areas libraries are already built to emulate W3C needed Spec improvements!

Comment: The book simply is very, very outdated. Modern Javascript engines do use very fast memory allocation structures under the hood for things that your code treats like arrays. You don't even have to do anything special.